# local xml won't load

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, theme

Following is my theme's `layout.xml`, but seems like it it not loaded

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <layout>
      <default>
        <reference name="content" after="*">
        <block type="cms/block" name="test.c"> 
            <action method="setBlockId">
                <block_id>contact</block_id>
            </action>
        </reference>
      </default>
    </layout>
```

I tried removing `after="*"` but it didn't work, is my syntax wrong?
It is located under `app/design/frontend/{my_theme}/{my_package}/layout/local.xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missing end block here follow below changes, and also replace `*` with `-`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
  <default>
    <reference name="content" after="-">
      <block type="cms/block" name="test.c"> 
        <action method="setBlockId">
            <block_id>contact</block_id>
        </action>
       </block> 
    </reference>
  </default>
</layout>
```

Comment: @Murtaza thanks,  i want to use it after content, but it shows before the content? Can i also use my handle and insert custom css file using `local.xml`

Comment: please check on which block you want to show this block and set after="thatblockName"

Answer (score 0):

Try bellow code

```
<reference name="content" after="*">
    <block type="cms/block" name="test.c">
        <action method="setBlockId">
            <block_id>contact</block_id>
        </action>
    </block>
</reference>
```